# Consume Kafka Messages and Post to REST API using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, rest

I have below the requirement to be implemented in Spring Boot.

How to achieve this?

1. Consume a message from a topic and Transform the message fields for the REST API
2. POST it to a REST API via HTTP or HTTPs.
3. Capture the API response.
4. Record any errors while posting the message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Kafka or Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka binder to receive the message.
It will deserialize it you, then you can transfrom it to object you want.
Then you can use (inject) RestTemplate (or Webclient for reactive) to post the message. It will send the message and receive the response. For error handling, you can use the default ones via try/catch, or implement your own by implementing `ResponseErrorHandler` .

Some useful links:

[RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template)

[RestTemplate Error handling](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling)

[Spring Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-spring-boot-application/)

Comment: Can i implement in single spring project?

Comment: As i understand your requirements, you have 2 projects, a kafka consumer which send the message over http, and another which recieve that message from the first.